# How to optimise a generic printing method

Tags: c#, collections

So I have this homework assignment and there's a part where I need a printing method which could print a table. A method should print a table with data from three different collections. Tables headers aren't the same. For example, the code I have so far is:

```
private void PrintExample<T>(string fileName, T message)
{
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fileName, true))
    {
        if (message.GetType() == typeof(string))
        {
            // print something here
        }

        else if (message.GetType() == typeof(SortedList<someClass, string>))
        {
            sw.WriteLine("-------------------------------------------------------------------");
            sw.WriteLine("|           1           |        2        |         3             |");
            sw.WriteLine("-------------------------------------------------------------------");
            foreach (KeyValuePair<someClass, string> kvp in message as SortedList<someClass, string>)
            {
                // print something here
            }
            sw.WriteLine("------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
            sw.WriteLine();
        }

        else if (message.GetType() == typeof(Dictionary<int, List<someClass>>))
        {
            sw.WriteLine("-------------------------------------------------------------------");
            sw.WriteLine("|     SOMETHING     |     Name    |          Something2           |");
            sw.WriteLine("-------------------------------------------------------------------");

            foreach (KeyValuePair<int, List<someClass>> kvp in message as Dictionary<int, List<someClass>>)
            {
                foreach (someClass date in kvp.Value)
                {
                    // print something here
                }
                sw.WriteLine("-------------------------------------------------------------------");
            }
            sw.WriteLine();
        }

        else if (message.GetType() == typeof(List<someClass>))
        {
            sw.WriteLine("--------------------------------------------------------------------");
            sw.WriteLine("|     other header     |             other header 7777             |");
            sw.WriteLine("--------------------------------------------------------------------");

            foreach (someClass date in message as List<someClass>)
            {
                // print something here
            }
            sw.WriteLine("----------------------------------------------------");
            sw.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

But I suppose that this isn't a good way of doing this kind of thing. Is there a way to optimize the code? By the way, the use of a generic method isn't mandatory, that's just the way I implemented the code.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Optimize in which way? Being more efficient or refactoring the code? Anyway, I'm not sure if this applies better in CodeReview.

Comment: Refactoring the code

Comment: Use `is string` instead of `GetType() == typeof(string)` for starters. You can move different rendering options to different methods. After that you could take advantage of overloading to get rid of the type check and have the compiler pick the correct method based on the parameter type

Comment: Can you please provide example instances of the possible `message` objects? And what the outputs should look like for each?

Comment: If for each type of `message` you need to print something completely different then you should go with three overloaded methods (three because I suppose `List<T>` and `SortedList<T>` might well be `IEnumerable<T>`. If content is the same (that's why fictional code is rarely useful) then you can use simplify code extracting a common `PrintImpl()` method and feed it from 1) overloads or 2) a function where you use `as IEnumerable<Something>` and check for `null` or `is IEnumerable<Something> list`. Note that to use generics here is completely useless (parameter might well be `object`).

Comment: Side note: yes, this should be posted in CodeReview but **NOT** in its current form. Fictional code and huge omissions are not for CR (and you should also better describe what this method is supposed to do).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a few suggestions. I'm not going so far as to recommend some final state, but just a few things that will help.

I'm approaching "optimize" from the standpoint of making the code easier to read and maintain. There's nothing going on in this code that would make me concerned about how fast it runs.

You're starting with this:

```
if (message.GetType() == typeof(string))
  // code to print the string
if (message.GetType() == typeof(SomethingElse))
  // code to print SomethingElse
```

A first step would be to put the code for each type of thing you want to print in its own method, so that now it looks like this.

```
if (message.GetType() == typeof(string))
  PrintString((string)message);
if (message.GetType() == typeof(SomethingElse))
  PrintSomethingElse((SomethingElse)message);
```

That's a small refactor. All it does it move code into separate methods. Now you've got one method that takes `message` and figures out which method to use to print it. Then you've got separate, smaller methods that are each responsible for printing just one type. That just accomplishes making the whole thing easier to read.

---

What's even better is if we don't have to check and argument to see what type it is. The code outside of `PrintExample<T>` already knows what type it's going to pass to the method. It's calling `PrintExample<string>()`, `PrintExample<SomethingElse>()`, etc.

So there's no reason to have one method that can take any type of argument, call it, and then revert back to trying to figure out what type it is.

Instead, given that there are finite number of things your code will know how to print, you could just write a method for each one of them, and make them public:

```
public void Print(string value)

public void Print(SomethingElse value)
```

This is even easier to work with. The generic method lets you call

```
PrintExample<ThisCouldBeAnything>(thing);
```

But what if `ThisCouldBeAnything` isn't actually a type that the method can print? If you have different methods for different types then if you have a variable of a certain type it's really easy to see whether or not there is a method to print it. It's also easy to call the right method.

A next step is to look for code that gets repeated and put it in separate methods or even separate classes.

If the methods for printing a `List<Something>` and `Dictionary<int, Something>` both have to print the details of `Something`, you can have one `PrintSomething` method that both of them call.

---

Here's something else to consider: You're creating methods that take various things and write strings that describe them. As-is, your class can only write to a file. What if you want most of this functionality but you don't want to write to a file? What if you want to write it to the console or do something else with it?

It might be better to put these in a separate class or classes and have the methods return `string` or pass the `StreamWriter` to the method or to the class. That way if a class wants to write something to a file, that class can use the "Printer" class or classes to do that. But if another class wants to do something else with the output, it can do that.

This becomes even more important if you want to be able to write unit tests. It's better to break up classes into separate responsibilities. One is responsible for converting `SomeClass` to a string output, and you can test that it does that correctly by comparing the string to what you expect. That would be more complicated if, in order to test, you had to write to a file and then open up the file and read it.